# SQL joining three tables returns extra NULL row

Tags: sql, join

I am joining three tables to see how long it takes a property maintenance person to do a task.  I need the property name, what the task was, how long it took, and who the person was.

The catch is that some tasks got entered into the system with no one's name, which is totally fine so it renders as NULL.  But to track how long it took to do a task, the tasks that had no name show fine as None with no time.  That is fine. The tasks with a person's name on it, show two rows - one for the dude and one for NULL.

I don't want the NULL/None if a guy's name is on the task.  Below you see a chopped down version of the query.  I only want the row that shows Mikhail.

Thoughts? Thanks for any help.

RESULT

```
1   2415    35719   NULL    Lobby ceiling and wall leaking
2   2415    35719   Mikhail Lobby ceiling and wall leaking
```

EXPECTED

```
2   2415    35719   Mikhail Lobby ceiling and wall leaking
```

Code:

```
SELECT  
    p.sCode "Property",
    p.sAddr1 "PropertyName",
    wo.scode,
    COALESCE(person.sfirstname + ' ' + person.ulastname, 'None'),
    wo.sbriefdesc,
    wo.spriority,
    wo.scategory,
    wo.ssubcat,
    ISNULL(wod.dtactstart, 0),
    ISNULL(wod.dtactfinish, 0),
    /* COALESCE(ROUND((CAST((wo.dtwcompl - wo.dtcall) AS FLOAT) * 24.0 * 60), 3), 0) AS TechTimeInMins */
    COALESCE(ROUND((CAST((wod.dtactfinish - wod.dtactstart) AS FLOAT) * 24.0), 3), 0) AS TechTimeInHours,
    COALESCE(ROUND((CAST((wod.dtactfinish - wod.dtactstart) AS FLOAT)), 3), 0) AS TechTimeInDays
FROM
    MM2WO wo
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    property p ON wo.hProperty = p.hMy
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    mm2wodet wod ON wod.hWo = wo.hMy
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    person ON person.hmy = wod.hperson
WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND wo.sstatus IN ('Work Completed')
ORDER BY  
    p.sAddr1 ASC, wo.scode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
From MM2WO wo
    left outer join property p on wo.hProperty = p.hMy
    left outer join mm2wodet wod on wo.hMy= wod.hWo 
    left outer join person on person.hmy = wod.hperson
     where 1 = 1 and  wod.hperson is not null and 
    person.sfirstname   is not null  and  person.ulastname  is not null
In this case id sfirstname or ulastname is null it will replace name with space for that person
```

.

Comment: I still get the NULL record along with the name record.

Comment: Property scode sfirstname sbriefdesc
1 2415 35719 NULL Lobby ceiling and wall leaking
2 2415 35719 Mikhail Lobby ceiling and wall leaking

Comment: changed one line

Comment: Hi Jin - I solved the problem! One of the joins, no the person table, was fetching a row with the person's ID# and another row with zero.  I added this into the conditions at the very bottom of the query:   and (wod.hperson > 1 or wod.hperson is null).  That has blocked the extra "zero" rows.  I was wrong, they were not NULL value-rows.  Thank for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Hi Jin - I think that your solution blocks the rows that have a NULL value in them.  I still need those rows to render.  Anyway, the zero thing was the problem.  Thx.